# Does the FBI keep track of people's library records?

Tags: realism, se7en

In the movie ***Se7en***, the detectives get the records of people who have read certain kinds of books (like nuclear weapons etc.). So that they can narrow down their list of suspects/can find them.

**Is this concept fictional or for real?**

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Basically, it's fictional (at least legally)

> Forty-eight states and the District of Columbia have laws protecting the confidentiality of library records. Two states, Kentucky and Hawaii, have attorney general's  opinions protecting library users' privacy.  The language of these provisions vary from state to state.  The majority of these laws declare that a library user's records and information are confidential, and **not subject to disclosure, unless certain conditions are met, such as a user's consent or the service of a court order.**
>
> [Source](http://www.ala.org/advocacy/privacy/statelaws)

BUT...there was such a program.

> As early as 1973, the FBI was running a program aimed at securing information about reading habits of many library users; this program was ultimately called the "Library Awareness Program". The Library Awareness Program was designed as a counterintelligence effort that would provide information to the FBI including the names and reading habits of users of many different libraries. The FBI was particularly interested in learning this type of information about foreign diplomats or their agents. It is clear that librarians and the public were unaware of this program until its existence was made public in an article published September 18, 1987 in the New York Times.
>
> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_Awareness_Program)

Comment: This obviously varies by location, but the public library system in my county doesn't keep records once a book has been turned in and any late fees paid

Comment: @Kevin Ah, I remember the old days when there was a thing attached to the inner front cover that would have your name and due date along with all the previous people that had checked out the book.  Actually, I may be thinking of my old school library, but still... in some places there was an *obvious* paper trail for as long as it lasted.

Comment: @Michael Yeah, I'm old enough to remember that as well. It was kind of cool to look at sometimes

Comment: @Michael My high school library had a book on lettering that both I and a classmate checked out several times.  Her signature got more refined each time.

Comment: @Michael in the public libraries here (UK) in the 80s/90s, the only information kept in the front was the due date, no PII.  My 6 paper library tickets (that was how many books I could have at once) didn't have records on them, so the library could only find out which books I had out at a given moment.  Now I can log on & find >3 years of loan history. That's the difference between paper record-keeping and databases - in the latter storing everything is cheap & invisible; in the former the system had to be designed more carefully, or the library would have been full of the wrong paper

Comment: Is it possible that the FBI in the movie were getting court orders to release the records of who borrowed specific books, though?  That's the sort of thing they might gloss over *actually mentioning* in a movie, but they still might have done it, right?

Comment: @Steve-O That's a very deep philosophical question you are asking.  If a tree falls in the woods in the movie and the camera isn't there to show it, did it make a sound?

Comment: @Michael I'm aware of the apparent implication, but I mean, movies skip over details like this all the time, to focus on the larger plot.  If the characters are driving from A to B, we don't necessarily see them take every turn along the way.  There are tropes about things like "you never see them pay the cabbie" and "no one ever goes to the washroom on TV."  And in this particular case, assuming they got a warrant changes the answer to the question from "it's fictional (because legality)" to "it's for real (but they didn't show all the steps)"

Comment: @Steve-O Questions like "do the characters pay the cabbie" or "do the characters use the washroom" can be answered affirmatively fairly easily because we can see implications of how the fictional universe presented works.  We see the characters have jobs and use money and eat and drinks. We often have no such insight into the legal workings - unless the authors explicitly show us it's just as plausible that the universe depicted doesn't have quite the same set of laws that we do.

Answer (score 10):

Via the Patriot Act, it is possible to request library records. However, librarians found this offensive, so they responded by only keeping the absolute minimum possible records. Therefore, the FBI may be able to see what you have checked out at the moment, but not what you have checked out in the past, because the library erased all records of those checkouts as soon as you returned them. The specifics may vary by library, but this is broad policy.

(I'll note that the answer by Paulie_D describes the state-level laws, but federal law supersedes state law. I'll also note that this law was made after Se7en released, so it couldn't have been used in the film, but you're asking about if it's possible in real life.)

[Example policy](https://www.spl.org/about-us/policies/confidentiality-of-patron-information/confidentiality-and-the-usa-patriot-act)

Comment: My library allows users to decide if they want to keep or not keep the records of items they check out.

Answer (score -1):

The US government monitors all kinds of internet traffic.   To say that they listen to private lines (whether internet or phone) but they do not listen to a publicly funded institution is a little ridiculous.

After 9/11 there were many monitoring agencies that picked up on government activity specifically on libraries.    All they have to do is save the information, as if a library deletes it, the info is still stored.    There is also no reason that our public libraries databases (internet connectivity) are Fort Knox-like.

So to assume that the FBI/CIA has discontinued doing this because the Patriotic Act or some other act is **RIDICULOUS**.    There are two reasons why we don't hear about it more now.

1. Since it is "illegal" (saying a govt agency unilaterally doing this is illegal is funny it is akin to making your dad eat his vegetables) they simply don't mention it anymore.
2. Since the knowledge shift for things that may help "bad" guys has shifted from books to the internet there is less of an emphasis on this.

However... There have been several stories about how people were tracked because of internet activity at libraries.   If you read about a story there are 50 more that happened that nobody heard about.

Comment: Please specify what features in your answer distinguish it from a rant / conspiracy theory argument. Some credible resources might greatly help.

Comment: blankip - the library wants Catcher in the Rye back...

Comment: @polfosolఠ_ఠ - wait so I gave examples and I could sit here and list hundreds off but this isn't the purpose of the site, yet you made no comment to the answer that the government doesn't do it because it is illegal.   So my question to you is what distinguishes your comment from any other paid government bot?   Yea the government would never do anything illegal.   Must be a conspiracy theory... jet I just named times they were caught not any huge conspiracy.   Just really uneducated comment.

Answer (score -1):

No, this is not realistic, not in any library staffed by librarians who have degrees from programs accredited by the American Library Association (ALA) and/or who adhere to the ALA's Code of Ethics, which should be all of them in the U.S.

Patron privacy and confidentiality are near the top of the list of important things librarians care about, just behind access for all and anti-censorship.

Point #3 of the [ALA Code of Ethics](http://www.ala.org/tools/ethics) states:

> We protect each library user's right to privacy and confidentiality with respect to information sought or received and resources consulted, borrowed, acquired or transmitted.

Item VII of the [Library Bill of Rights](http://www.ala.org/advocacy/intfreedom/librarybill) states:

> All people, regardless of origin, age, background, or views, possess a right to privacy and confidentiality in their library use. Libraries should advocate for, educate about, and protect people’s privacy, safeguarding all library use data, including personally identifiable information.

The simplest way to ensure that patrons' borrowing records are private and secure is not to retain them at all, which is, in fact, how things work at the libraries I patronize.

The bad guys can't get what doesn't exist.